# Question About $G_{\delta}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have question about $G_\delta$ set 
Here it is

For any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $ Cl(A)/A$ is countable, then $A$ is $G_\delta$. Note that $Cl$ is closure for $A$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The closure of $A$ divided by $A$ is countable?? What kind of quotient is that??

Comment: Is $/$ a typo for the set-subtraction symbol $\setminus$?

Comment: If $Cl(A)\setminus A$ is countable, then $A$ is a $G_\delta$ because: (1) $A$ is the intersection of $Cl(A)$ and $\mathbb R\setminus(Cl(A)\setminus A);$ (2) $Cl(A)$ is a closed set; (3) a closed set is a $G_\delta;$ (4) the complement of a countable set is a $G_\delta;$ (5) the intersection of two $G_\delta$ sets is a $G_\delta.$